# Condition on subsets of normed linear space such that "every real valued continuous function on the subset is uniformly continuous" imply boundedness

Tags: soft-question, metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces, uniform-continuity

If $A$ is a connected subset of a real normed linear space such that every real valued continuous function on $A$ is uniformly continuous , then is it true that $A$ is bounded ? If not , then what if we restrict $A$ to be path connected ? Even if not in this case , does convex property on $A$ guarantee boundness ? Do we require the real normed linear space to be finite dimensional ?  ( The only thing I know is that if $X$ is a metric space such that every real valued continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous , then $X$ is complete )

Comment: With smile: have you considered one-question-at-one-time?

Comment: If our $A$ contains a ray (i.e. a set of the form $\{v+wt : t\ge 0\}$) then we can find a real-valued continuous, but not uniformly continuous function on $A$ - we just extend a non-uniformly-continuous function over a ray.) I suspect that such method can apply on an unbounded convex set.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a connected metric space such that every real valued continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous, then $X$ is compact.  In particular, it is bounded.

Proof:
If $X$ is not compact, there is a sequence $S = \{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with no convergent subsequence.   Then for each $n$ there is $\epsilon_n > 0$ such that the ball $B_{\epsilon_n}(x_n)$ contains no members of $S$ except $x_n$.   We may assume  $\epsilon_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  Define
a function $f$ on $X$ by:

$$f(x) = \sup(0, \sup_n (1 - 2 d(x, x_n)/\epsilon_n))$$

Note that for any $x$ there is at most one $x_n$ with $2 d(x,x_n) < \epsilon_n$.  Then $f$ is continuous, but not uniformly continuous. 
In fact, $f(x_n) = 1$ but $f(x) = 0$ if  $d(x,x_n) = \epsilon_n/2$ (and by connectedness, if $\epsilon_n/2$ is small enough there is such an $x$).